# create varchar column from boolean columns postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a varchar column containing color value from boolean columns, here's the table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE public.prosp(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    isblack bool,
    isyellow bool,
    isgreen bool
);
```

I want to add a column called color containg for example : `green`

if `isgreen = true`, I tried this and it worked

```
SELECT
"id",    
  CASE WHEN "isblack" THEN 'black; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "isyellow" THEN 'yellow; ' ELSE '' END || 
  CASE WHEN "isgreen" THEN 'green; ' ELSE '' END
  AS couleurs
FROM public.prosp
```

now I need to put the result of the above expression in `color` column.

Thanks.

Comment: how should the output look like? do you need a delimited result if multiple conditions are true?

Comment: maybe create a view that contains your varchar color column instead

Comment: yes, i want it to be delimited if multiple conditions are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
alter table public.prosp add column color varchar(255);

update public.prosp
    set color = (CASE WHEN isblack THEN 'black; ' ELSE '' END) ||
                (CASE WHEN isyellow THEN 'yellow; ' ELSE '' END) || 
                (CASE WHEN isgreen THEN 'green; ' ELSE '' END);
```

I should note that often this would be done using `concat_ws()`:

```
update public.prosp
    set color = concat_ws(',',
                          (CASE WHEN isblack THEN 'black' END),
                          (CASE WHEN isyellow THEN 'yellow' END),
                          (CASE WHEN isgreen THEN 'green' END)
                         );
```

This puts a comma *between* the values, rather than a semicolon at the end.